# Unable to manage product images in catalog

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, catalog, product-images

Although product images appear normal on the front-end, I'm unable to manage photos on the back-end.  In the product catalog it appears as if none of the products have images!

Also, when I upload a new image, the upload appears to work successfully.  However, no images appear in the image list after upload.

Comment: have you just applied a patch?

Comment: Yes, there  was a patch I applied recently.  I was thinking of rolling it back to see what happens.

Comment: There are known problems with applying certain patches and image uploading. If you know which patch it was please search on Magento Stackexchange for questions regarding that patch and I'm sure you'll find the answer. Alternatively let us know which patch it was and we'll help you get to the bottom of it.